# Find the convergent subsequences of $x_k=((-1)^k , \frac1k , (-2)^{3k})$ which converge to different limits.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Find the convergent subsequences of 
$x_k=((-1)^k , \dfrac1k , (-2)^{3k})$,
which converge to different limits.

I think $x_k=((-1)^{2k} , \dfrac{1}{2k} , (-2)^{6k})$ can be subsequences for no sure. However they converge to same limits. Except $(-1)^{2k}$

Comment: It looks like any subsequence is going to diverge, the final component has subsequences tending to both $+\infty$ and $-\infty$.

Comment: $x_{2k}$ and $x_{2k+1}$.